# Using JQuery to set focus on a textbox based on it's CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to select all of the text in a textbox when the user sets focus to it.  I only want to do this for specific textboxes, and using the class assigned to them seems to be the simplest way.  Currently I'm using:

```
$("input[type='text']").click(function () {
    $(this).select();
});
```

which works on all textboxes but I can't figure out how to modify it to do the select only if the textbox has the class 'positionField' assigned to it.

Comment: The title says you want to set focus, but the question is about selecting the text.

Answer (score 1):

use the period to signify class in a Jquery selector:

```
$(".yourClassName").click(function () {
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: Ugh, was right there in front of me.  Works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the following:

```
$("input[type='text'].positionField").click(function () {
    $(this).select();
}
```